# ffmpeg - drawtext filter producing file with no streams

Tags: aws-lambda, ffmpeg

I am trying to get ffmpeg's drawtext filter working in an AWS lambda. Other operations like concatenating and trimming files works. But drawtext fails for some reason. I run the exact same command on my local machine and it runs fine.

The output is below. The first line shows the parameters passed to ffmpeg.
You can see at the end of the following output that it's only processing 3 frames before exiting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
2022-07-24T00:38:12.120Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    About to execute step:  [
  '-y',
  '-v',
  'repeat+level+verbose',
  '-i',
  '/tmp/out_0.mp4',
  '-vf',
  "drawtext=fontfile=DejaVuSans.ttf:text='Helloooo':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.7:boxborderw=5:x=10:y=h-th-10",
  '-c:a',
  'copy',
  '/tmp/out_1.mp4'
]
2022-07-24T00:38:12.440Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info] ffmpeg version N-62110-g4d45f5acbd-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
[info]   built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
[info]   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
[info]   libavutil      57. 26.100 / 57. 26.100
[info]   libavcodec     59. 33.100 / 59. 33.100
[info]   libavformat    59. 24.100 / 59. 24.100
[info]   libavdevice    59.  6.100 / 59.  6.100
[info]   libavfilter     8. 40.100 /  8. 40.100
[info]   libswscale      6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100
[info]   libswresample   4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
[info]   libpostproc    56.  5.100 / 56.  5.100

2022-07-24T00:38:12.682Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [h264 @ 0x63bc000] [verbose] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p

2022-07-24T00:38:13.321Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info] Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/out_0.mp4':
[info]   Metadata:
[info]     major_brand     : isom
[info]     minor_version   : 512
[info]     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
[info]     encoder         : Lavf59.24.100
[info]   Duration: 00:00:30.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5135 kb/s
[info]   Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, progressive, left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4998 kb/s, 
2022-07-24T00:38:13.321Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    29.98 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       handler_name    : VideoHandler
[info]       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

2022-07-24T00:38:13.341Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info]   Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       handler_name    : SoundHandler
[info]       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

2022-07-24T00:38:13.440Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info] Stream mapping:
[info]   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[info]   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
[info] Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

2022-07-24T00:38:13.440Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [h264 @ 0x63e57c0] [verbose] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p

2022-07-24T00:38:15.321Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6699840] [verbose] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 fr:30/1 sar:1/1

2022-07-24T00:38:16.121Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [libx264 @ 0x63c1140] [info] using SAR=1/1

2022-07-24T00:38:16.222Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [libx264 @ 0x63c1140] [info] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2

2022-07-24T00:38:16.341Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [libx264 @ 0x63c1140] [info] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x63c1140] [info] 
2022-07-24T00:38:16.360Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00

2022-07-24T00:38:16.642Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info] Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/out_1.mp4':
[info]   Metadata:
[info]     major_brand     : isom
[info]     minor_version   : 512
[info]     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
[info]     encoder         : Lavf59.24.100

2022-07-24T00:38:16.881Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info]   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, progressive, left), 1920x1080 (0x0) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn (default)
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       handler_name    : VideoHandler
[info]       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[info]       encoder         : Lavc59.33.100 libx264
[info]     Side data:
[info]       cpb: 
2022-07-24T00:38:16.900Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A

2022-07-24T00:38:16.960Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info]   Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       handler_name    : SoundHandler
[info]       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

2022-07-24T00:38:17.321Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info] frame=    1 fps=0.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.07 bitrate=   5.1kbits/s speed=0.0708x    
2022-07-24T00:38:17.502Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info] frame=    1 fps=0.3 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.09 bitrate=   4.0kbits/s speed=0.0247x    
2022-07-24T00:38:23.920Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    [info] frame=    2 fps=0.3 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.13 bitrate=   2.8kbits/s speed=0.0204x    
2022-07-24T00:38:38.942Z    8812cc07-d9e4-4750-8c74-1f987b7ca873    INFO    Close: Exit code:  null
```

Comment: What version of ffmpeg are you using? When you test locally, do you use the exact same version?

Comment: I tested using the exact same version locally and with the lambda - turns out the issue was that I hadn't upped the lambda's memory from the default 128MB.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue had nothing to do with ffmpeg. I simply hadn't given the lambda enough memory. Giving the lambda more memory fixed it.